# How solid state laser is tuned?

Tags: laser, fine-tuning

My understanding about solid state laser is sample as a source of exciting (lamp ,laser beam, ..) pump the crystal wich emite a certaine range of infrared wavelength sometime in visible range, this one will resonate between to mirrors one is fully reflecting and the other one partially reflecting.

In my case i am interested in alexandrite laser and i did some researsh about it absorption specrta
[image: absorption]
As shown in the graph the top absorption is at 420nm and 600nm, and  Emission wavelengths are typically between 700nm and 800nm in many cases around 750nm, where the maximum laser gain. So my question is how the output wavelength is selected? Is it by controlling the pumped light? Or by filtring the output?
Thank you.

Comment: Controlling the finesse of the cavity (which I consider different from filtering the output).

Comment: @JonCuster that what i meant, does the pumping wavelength affect anything?

Comment: Different efficiency of converting external pump power to populations of the initial internal states, potentially different efficiencies for transitions from the pumped internal states to the states that will lase. If multiple possible internal states that could lase, you might have different efficiencies populating those through different pump wavelengths.

Comment: @JonCuster thank you for your time, so here what i did understand from your comment if the right wavelenght is pumped to the crystal it will excite effecienlly.  (external pump power=> light)( to the states that will lase=> exciting state of the gain medium wich is the crystal).

Comment: Pretty much. Once upon a time a Nd:YAG laser was pumped with a flashlamp (well, even back to ruby lasers). Once they started pumping with a diode laser their wall efficiency went up dramatically, such that you could have a green (doubled YAG) laser in the palm of your hand powered by a battery.